# Controlling Bluetooth RHD3D Shutter Glasses

Tags: android, 3d, bluetooth, shutter

I have been searching everywhere for an answer to this.  My end goal is to create a program that will allow an Android device (or Arduino) to control a set of shutter glasses.  I have a decent amount of experience in electronics and multicontrollers, so have a good grasp of different communications protocols, but I'm new to Bluetooth.  The standard I'd like to go with is the Bluetooth RF (or RHD3D or Real HD 3d) that is summarized here:

http://www.fullhd3dglasses.com/

I have a set right now and it's not pairing with my PC or any Android device (I have about 10 from different era's, including LG G2).  I guess I have a couple of questions.

The first is if it will even be possible to communicate using Bluetooth if the device is not designed specifically to communicate with it (ie unrooted android phone).  In essence, can you communicate over Bluetooth without the device being simply "paired", kind of like RS232, and maybe a link to a good tutorial on how I would do that.

If it is possible, my second question would be if anyone would have any idea where I can find more information on the specific protocol and how it actually communicates, ie sends the different signals to turn on and off the different shutters to each eye?  Timing diagrams would be awesome.  I did find this:

https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=271498

but it says nothing about being based on "Full 3d HD".  I've also spent a few hours going through the Bluetooth SIG site, and have learned some things about the standard, but not much about any specifics related to what I'm trying to do.

I truly appreciate any help in either answering these questions, or pointing me in the direction of where I can find the answers, as I've hit a brick wall.

Comment: Anybody have any idea's on this?  Any direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: Wow, 7 years later, still no answer :-/ I'm trying to do the exact same thing, but I'm still not able to find good information. In fact it might be even harder to find good information now, as some sites as fullhd3dglasses.com (listed above) do no longer exist...
Did you eventually succeed in your project?